# How can I anchor 4 linear layouts to the bottom of a linear layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout, adt

As you can see here, I have created 4 linear layouts circled with yellow, green, blue, and purple to distinguish between the different horizontals. I would like to anchor all 4 of these layouts to the bottom of the main linear layout as shown in red. I was looking for the easiest solution to my problem. Perhaps a RelativeLayout for the main layout, but then how would I get all 4 linear layouts to anchor to the bottom and stacked on top of each other in this order? Sorry for not posting code, but the code for all the buttons would probably be too long.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/po"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Q" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="W"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="E"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="R"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="T"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Y"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="U"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="I"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="O"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="P"
         />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="9" >

            <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="S"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="D"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="F"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="G"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="H"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="J"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="K"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="L"
         />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Z" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="X"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="C"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="V"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="B"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="N"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="M"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text=","
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="."
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="\?"
         />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Space"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="75"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Bkspc"
         />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to use alignParentBottom, Use RelativeLayout as a parent view. And show me your code if possible.

Comment: @Prince Posted. I also want to keep txtQuestion and btnClear at top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your xml in following way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Q" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="W" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="E" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="R" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="T" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Y" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="U" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="I" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="O" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="P" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="S" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="D" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="F" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="G" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="H" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="J" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="K" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="L" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Z" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="V" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="B" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="N" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="M" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="," />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="." />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="\?" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:text="Space" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:text="Bkspc" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

OUTOUT :

[image]

Comment: It kept btnClear and txtQuestion at the top and took away all the buttons as if they're off screen.

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter Welcome. Glad to help you. Happy codding :)

Answer (score 2):

Use RelativeLayout as the parent Layout.Then Use alignParentBottom property to set All the layouts at the bottom.

Comment: To keep both of them at top use alignParentTop = true for your TextView
 and for btnclear use alignLayoutBelow = "@+id/txtViewId"